# Gatsby theme yarn workspaces

Tags: node.js, gatsby, yarnpkg, workspace, chalk

May you help me with an error in Gatsby? When I use yarn workspaces to start the development of theme, I get an error while installing the Gatsby dependency on my workspace.
Look this.

```
error C:\Users\Kirito\Desktop\ninja-react\node_modules\gatsby-cli: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/postinstall.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\Kirito\Desktop\ninja-react\node_modules\gatsby-cli
Output:
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:311
      throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'project_folder\node_modules\chalk\source'.
```

My env: Node 14.15.0 - Yarn 1.22.11.

My package json in root:

```
{
  "workspaces": [
    "sites/theme-dev",
    "packages/gatsby-theme-docs"
  ],
  "private": true
}
```

I accomplished to install react and react-dom normally, but with Gatsby have a conflict.

```
{
  "name": "theme-dev",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why shout at us?

Comment: Sorry :c I'm desperate a little ahhahaha

Answer (score 1):

According to [this GitHub](https://github.com/addyosmani/a11y/issues/13) thread try:

1. Install manually the needed dependencies by:

   ```
   npm install chalk
   npm install each-async
   npm install indent-string
   ```
2. Upgrade your Node version, remove your `node_modules` and reinstall all dependencies again.

Remember to clean cache in each trial by running `gatsby clean` command.

Other interesting threads:

- https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa/issues/152